# Installing GeoIP On WAMP

Tags: wamp, wampserver, geoip, installation

I found about this PHP Extension before few days. Can anyone explain me how to install GeoIP on WAMP?

Comment: Off-topic as unrelated to programming. Go to superuser or serverfault. I cannot flag this question as there is an open bounty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geoip extetion type is PECL extetion that for installing it in windows not the same other pear extention ( just copy theme in ext directory  and in php.ini add extension = geoip.dll ).
geoip.dll  in php 5.3 not avaible and and if you want use it i suggest you read this doc carfeully [thislink](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) and  use **"Using mod_geoip"** with PHP method.'
be win ;)

Comment: I copied php_geoip.dll and php_geoip.pdb to wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext directory. And edited php.ini file to add extension=php_geoip.dll . Then I restarted wamp server. But I couldn't found the extension. I checked it in phpinfo. I am using php5.4.3. Is there any mistake in the procedure I did? Please help me

Comment: I have tried this solution but it does not works.Please help

Comment: Having the same problem.

Comment: Did everything but extension is not loaded. Don't know why ? Using Xampp on windows 7

Answer (score 7):

I got solution myself.

### Here the steps:

- First download `geoip dll` file ***respectively my phpversion***  from
  http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip.In my case my php vesion is 5.5.So download the geoip files from http://pecl.php.net/get/geoip-1.0.8.tgz
- Copy *`php_geoip.dll`* and *`php_geoip.pdb`* file paste it to
  *`wamp\bin\php\php[PHP_Version]\`*
- add the line `extension=php_geoip.dll` in php.ini file for enable php geoip extension on wampserver
- ***then restart your wamp***
- check php info.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do two things:

1. Place the extension / file into PHP's \ext folder.

   extension=geoip.dll
2. Edit PHP's php.ini file to load the extension and set up any of it's settings. *Though I don't think there are any php.ini settings for this extension.

Answer (score 0):

To PHP 7.2.0 and forward:

Use this file to add an extension: phpForApache.ini

Add:

extension=geoip